# rtmp live streaming cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am running `nginx rtmp module` on an ec2-instance and also, have mounted s3 with the help of `goofys(/var/mounted-s3-dir)` on the ec2-instance.

Below is the nginx config of my server.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        application live {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /var/mounted-s3-dir;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to play the hls stream through s3 via cloudfront. I want to push the rtmp stream to s3 and play rtmp stream via cloudfront. It has higher latency. I want to reduce the latency by 2-3 seconds using rtmp cloudfront. Could you assist me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Arut had done great job for `nginx-rtmp-module`, but it has no GOP cache feature, so besides latency results from cloudfront, main latency is because of `nginx-rtmp-module` itself.
I've added GOP cache feature for `nginx-rtmp-module`: https://github.com/winshining/nginx-http-flv-module, compared with `nginx-rtmp-module`, it reduces latency by 2~5s, maybe it will help you.